# Third-party library not found when using custom Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, plugins

I have create my first Maven plugin, it uses a third-party library (org.twdata.maven:mojo-executor:2.3.0) and it is deployed into our corporate Nexus. When I use my Maven plugin, it complains that some classes (from org.twdata.maven:mojo-executor:2.3.0) are missing.

How should I publish the plugin to determine the Maven to download the mojo-executor, too?

The plugins's pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>aaa</groupId>
<artifactId>bbb</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.version>3.3.9</maven.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-artifact-transfer</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twdata.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>mojo-executor</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>13.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>descriptor</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>help-goal</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>helpmojo</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: How did you add the dependency to your Maven plugin?

Comment: As a dependency:    <dependency><groupId>org.twdata.maven</groupId><artifactId>mojo-executor</artifactId><version>2.3.1</version></dependency>

Comment: Inside the POM of the plugin that you build?

Comment: Yes, in the project's pom.xml.

Comment: Maybe you add the plugins pom to the question.